# Create dictionary from a list of lists by using maxheap in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, max-heap

What I know is that creating a maxheap in Python is below:
The syntax of `heapq.heappush(heap, value)`

```
li = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]

maxheap = [-val for val in li]
heapq.heapify(maxheap)

heapq.heappush(maxheap, -10)         
print('maxheap = ', maxheap)       # [-10, -7, -9, -1, -3, -5]
```

I found a famous interview question and one of its solution.

"Given a list of the scores of different students, items, where items[i] = [IDi, scorei] represents one score from a student with IDi, calculate each student's top five average.
Return the answer as an array of pairs result, where result[j] = [IDj, topFiveAveragej] represents the student with IDj and their top five average. Sort result by IDj in increasing order.
A student's top five average is calculated by taking the sum of their top five scores and dividing it by 5 using integer division."

I saw one of solutions using maxheap and a part of it is below.

```
# items = [[1,91],[1,92],[2,93],[2,97],[1,60],[2,77],[1,65],[1,87],[1,100],[2,100],[2,76]]

def highFive(self, items):
    seen = defaultdict(list)
    
    for s_id, score in items:
        heapq.heappush(seen[s_id], -score)
    
    # output seen is {1: [-100, -91, -92, -65, -87, -60], 2: [-100, -97, -77, -93, -76]})
    print("seen = ", seen) 
    ...
```

This short code is mysterious for me (I'm a Java Dev. and started learning Python recently and my question is not about the algorithm of this solution ).

I know how to create a maxhep for a given integer list and how to create dictionary using defaultdict respectively, but don't understand how this short code doing altogether without even writing some codes which are used when create a dictionary and heap?

First, this code doesn't even write `heapq.heapify(seen)` to create maxheap.
Simply create default empty dictionary seen, and then looping input items and directly `heapq.heappush(seen[s_id], -score)`

Second, I printed out `seen[s_id]` in each iteration.
How come dictionary is created after `seen[s_id]` even without `append()` method like `seen[s_id].append(score)`?

```
for s_id, score in items:
    id_ = seen[s_id]
    print("\nseen[{0}] = {1}".format(s_id, id_))

    heapq.heappush(id_, -score)         
    ...

output: 
seen[1] = []

seen[1] = [-91]

seen[2] = []

seen[2] = [-93]

seen[1] = [-92, -91]

seen[2] = [-97, -93]

seen[1] = [-92, -91, -60]

seen[1] = [-92, -91, -60, -65]

seen[1] = [-92, -91, -60, -65, -87]

seen[2] = [-97, -93, -77]

seen[2] = [-100, -97, -77, -93]
```

Comment: `defaultdict` is just a `dict` that allows you to set a default value for a missing key, in your code you can see `seen` is set to be a defaultdict with a default value of a list. Now if you try to access a `key` from `seen` which doesn't exist yet, you'll get an empty list instead. While `heapq.heappush` just performs a heap push to a heap (or list).
Here are a couple of links to help you with your question: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappush and https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.

Answer (score 1):

> First, this code doesn't even write heapq.heapify(seen) to create
> maxheap. Simply create default empty dictionary seen, and then looping
> input items and directly heapq.heappush(seen[s_id], -score)

`heapq.heapify(myList)` changes the order of the elements in the list `myList` so that it satisfies the properties of a heap. However, if `myList` is an empty list, then this operation is not needed. The empty list already satisfies the properties of a heap.

Since `seen` is a `defaultdict` and not just a regular `dict`, an entry for `seen[s_id]` is created automatically, and initialised to an empty list, if this entry doesn't exist already.

> Second, I printed out seen[s_id] in each iteration. How come
> dictionary is created after seen[s_id] even without append() method
> like seen[s_id].append(score)?

Note that `heapq.heappush(seen[s_id], score)` and `seen[s_id].append(score)` are almost equivalent. The only difference is that `append` adds the element at the end of the list, whereas `heapq.heappush` adds the element at some position so that the list still satisfies the properties of a heap.

As an illustration, the three following codes produce the same result:

```py
li = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]

maxheap = [-val for val in li]
heapq.heapify(maxheap)
```

```py
li = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]

maxheap = []
for val in li:
  maxheap.append(-val)
heapq.heapify(maxheap)
```

```py
li = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]

maxheap = []
for val in li:
  heapq.heappush(maxheap, -val)
```